# How to get the weekday string representation for a date Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the weekday of a date (Wednesday, Tuesday) but I can't seem to find a good way to actually get the string. This is what I'm doing:

```
internal func fromToday(daysAgo: Date) -> String {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    let startOfNow = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let startOfTimeStamp = calendar.startOfDay(for: daysAgo)
    let numDaysDifference = abs(calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startOfNow, to: startOfTimeStamp).day!)
    let daysAgoComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from: daysAgo)

    var hour = daysAgoComponents.hour!
    var timeOfDay = "AM"

    if hour >= 13 {
        hour -= 12
        timeOfDay = "PM"
    }

    var res = "\(hour):\(daysAgoComponents.minute!)\(timeOfDay)"

    if calendar.isDateInYesterday(daysAgo) {
        res = "Yesterday"
    } else if numDaysDifference < 8 && numDaysDifference > 1 {
        res = stringFromWeekday(day: daysAgoComponents.weekday!) // HERE THIS IS WHAT IM ASKING ABOUT IGNORE OTHER IFS
    } else if numDaysDifference >= 8 {
        res = stringFromDate(day: daysAgo)
    }

    return res
}

fileprivate func stringFromWeekday(day: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

    if formatter.weekdaySymbols.count < day {
        print("ConversationTVC - \(day) is not a valid day of the week")
    }

    return formatter.weekdaySymbols[day]
}
```

Specifically, the line:

```
else if numDaysDifference < 8 && numDaysDifference > 1 
    res = stringFromWeekday(day: daysAgoComponents.weekday!)`
```

I think the issue has to do with `weekdaySymbols`

How do I get the string representation of the day of the week X days ago given a Date?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I wasn't subtracting 1 from day, weekday returns 1-7 and weekday symbols is 0-6